# How to call Confirmation Message before delete in ActionLink and then Controller to delete

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

Below is my Webgrid column "Actions" where i have placed Edit and Delete options. I want to give one confirmation message before going to controller. Below is code which is not working for me

```
 grid.Column(header: "Actions", format: (item) =>
           new HtmlString(
           Html.ActionLink("Edit", "GetEditRecord", new { id = item.id }, new {@class = "ActionEdit"}).ToString()  +
                           Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id }, new {@class = "ActionDelete", OnClientClick="test();"} ) .ToString()
                               ))
```

And below is the Javascript function

```
<script language="javascript">
function test() {
    alert("Hello\nHow are you?");
    //changeasset.class = "cd-panel from-right AddAssetForm is-visible";
}
    </script>
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function,

```
function test(){
     confirm('do you want to delete this');
}
```

Comment: again not calling above function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to bind a click event listener in the ActionLink with the 'OnClientClick' binding, I would bind the listener in the client code.

```
var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.ActionDelete');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(deleteLinks, function(link){
   link.addEventListener('click', test, false);
});
```